# Java set private value out of class

Tags: java

I'm trying to set and change default private value from out of class. But that doesn't work. For example i have `G` class and i have this method into that:

```
private static long exitTimeout = 0L;
```

now i'm define setter and getter for that such as:

```
public static long getExitTimeout() {
    return exit_timeout;
}

public static void setExitTimeout(long timeout) {
    exitTimeout = timeout;
}
```

Now I'm trying to get and set value of out class, for example:

```
public void getAndSet() {
    long timeout = G.getExitTimeout();
    if (timeout + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        //------------------
    } else {
    }
    G.setExitTimeout(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Log.e("new value: ", timeout + "");
}
```

timeout value is 0 alwayes

Comment: I assume `exit_timeout` is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getExitTimeout` returns the value of a different variable than the one set by `setExitTimeout` (`exit_timeout` vs. `exitTimeout`).

Answer (score 0):

Your program does the following:

1. Get the timeout value (the default 0 at this point)
2. Set the timeout value (to new value)
3. Print the value obtained in step 1.

Before printing, you should call `timeout = getExitTimeout()` again so you get the newly set value that was assigned in step 2, so that your program looks like this:

1. Get the timeout value (the default 0 at this point)
2. Set the timeout value (to new value)
3. Get the timeout value
4. Print the value obtained in the most recent get (step 3).

Answer (score 0):

Before print you have to call : `getExitTimeout()` method